# Group the class and Count users using lodash/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, lodash

Got an array list which has list of classes and users who attended; Needed an output which displays the user attended by grouping the classes and counting the total users;

```
var arrList = [
  { class: 'one', user: 'user1' },
  { class: 'two', user: 'user1' },
  { class: 'two', user: 'user2' },
  { class: 'one', user: 'user3' },
  { class: 'two', user: 'user3' },
  { class: 'three', user: 'user1' },
  { class: 'four', user: 'user1' }
];

// output
[
  { class: 'one', user: [ 'user1', 'user2', 'user3' ], count: 3 },
  { class: 'two', user: [ 'user1', 'user3' ], count: 2 },
  { class: 'three', user: [ 'user1' ], count: 1 },
  { class: 'four', user: [ 'user1' ], count: 1 } 
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `_.groupBy()` to collect the object by the `class` key, and then map to the required form.

A solution with chaining (requires full import of the lodash package):

```js
const arrList = [{"class":"one","user":"user1"},{"class":"two","user":"user1"},{"class":"two","user":"user2"},{"class":"one","user":"user3"},{"class":"two","user":"user3"},{"class":"three","user":"user1"},{"class":"four","user":"user1"}];

const result = _(arrList)
  .groupBy('class')
  .map((group, key) => ({
    class: key,
    user: _.map(group, 'user'),
    count: group.length
  }))
  .value();
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

A solution using `_.flow()` (can import just what you need from the lodash package):

```js
const { flow, partialRight: pr, groupBy, map } = _; // replace with imports in your project

const fn = flow(
  pr(groupBy, 'class'),
  pr(map, (group, key) => ({
    class: key,
    user: map(group, 'user'),
    count: group.length
  }))
);
  
const arrList = [{"class":"one","user":"user1"},{"class":"two","user":"user1"},{"class":"two","user":"user2"},{"class":"one","user":"user3"},{"class":"two","user":"user3"},{"class":"three","user":"user1"},{"class":"four","user":"user1"}];

const result = fn(arrList);
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: If the same has to be implemented using simple javascript. What would be the approach? Hash tables? Maps?

Comment: Reduce to an object or a Map, and then Object.values or Map.values with spread.